# Partial implementation of an abstract method?

Tags: java, methods, abstract

For example, I have many classes that all need a certain method.
In this method, all these classes need one line of code, the remainder of the method is different.

How could I achieve something like this:

```
void method(){
    everybodyDoesThisStuff;

    // more individual stuff 

    // more individual stuff
}
```

Abstract methods cannot have a body, and if you were not to make it abstract you would then override the method and lose it.

Comment: There's not any really good way to do it other than to pull out everybodyDoesThisStuff into a method that you explicitly call from each overrider of `method()`.

Comment: make `individualStuff()` and `moreIndividualStuff()` abstract methods and call them from `method()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes that's what I'm currently doing, I was just wondering if something like the above was possible. This way I wouldn't have to call that method in a 100 different classes.

Comment: You can override it and still can super.method() to access that method from a parent class in a derived class.

Comment: This makes me think of the [call super antipattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html) - it's not exactly the same as having to call the super method, but it is requiring *some* method to be called for the correct functioning of the method.

Comment: @Vucko  Nice!!! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for

Comment: @MitchWeaver really? Exactly? What if you forget to call super? There are *much* better approaches in the answers.

Comment: @AndyTurner haha... eh I guess it doesn't relieve my problem then. Definitely looks cleaner to just call super than another method I guess.

Comment: `Item 18: Prefer interfaces to abstract classes` and its what **OOP** about smaller method make application happy (Easier for testing and maintaining) and `interface` can fix your problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should make the method that does the "more individual stuff" abstract, not the method itself.

```
// AbstractBase.java
public abstract class AbstractBase {
    public final void method() {
        everybodyDoesThisStuff();
        doIndividualStuff();
    }

    abstract void doIndividualStuff();

    private void everybodyDoesThisStuff() {
        // stuff that everybody does
    }
}

// ConcreteClass.java
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractBase {
    void doIndividualStuff() {
         // do my individual stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's important that `everybodyDoesThisStuff()` is indeed done upon each call to `method` one could even make `method` `final`.

Comment: This is called the [Template Method  pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html).

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to require all subclasses to call `super.method()`. The problem is that there's no way to actually enforce that. Another option is to create a separate method that internally executes the required line and then calls an abstract method:

```
public final void method() {
    callEveryTime();
    doMethod();
}

protected abstract void doMethod();
```

Note that `method()` is `public final` so it can be called anywhere but not overridden, whereas `doMethod()` is `protected` so it can be overridden but not called outside its package (or subclasses).

Comment: This is called the [Template Method  pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can make a normal method call an abstract method:

```
void foo(){
    // do stuff
    bar(); // let the abstract method do the rest
}
abstract void bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking yourself whether you need partial implementations of an abstract method, it's usually time to reconsider the granularity of your design.

Why not extract `everybodyDoesThisStuff` into a separate method and put it in an `Interface`?

Comment: Can you post an example?